# Reducing Eddy Currents?

Tags: electromagnetism

A conductor that passes a magnetic field, decreases its velocity due to the opposing magnetic forces created by the Eddy Currents.

This "magnetic breaking" effect can be reduced if we change the shape of the conductor from a bar, to a this conductor like this:

[image]

What I understand is that conductor above has a higher resistance and reduces the eddy currents. However, what if the air gaps are conductors? Here is where I find laminated conductors to be useful like so:

[image]

However, what is the difference? I believe the laminated conductor can carry more current(i/e higher current capacity) than the one above. The whole point is reducing eddy currents(the magnetic breaking)in electric motors, or generators... and not affecting its electric properties by increasing its resistance and reducing its current capacity.

Am I correct here or is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

I would not say I completely understand your question, but ill explain to you the use of laminating conductors to reduce eddy currents.

First a mistake in your picture, where you say neighbouring loops in opposition, both have current in anti clockwise direction, they are not opposing!

So the thing is that, when a conductor has larger area, larger potential difference is available at its two ends because of interaction with greater magnetic flux, also the current can pass through larger area and hence effective resistance for that current is less; more potential difference and less resistance leads to more current.

Whereas, when we laminate the conductor after making slots in between, we reduce the area and interaction of magnetic flux which leads to development of smaller potentials across the slotted arms of the conductor, the reduced area also results in a higher resistance. These factors "multiply" together to reduce the current in each arm. Even if you add the current of all arms it is still lesser than what was originally available in the unslotted and laminated conductor.

Then again the interaction of stopping mechanism can be closely related to the force obtained by the formula of $\tau = NIAB $. Again smaller current and area multiply together to reduce the breaking effect and even on adding the effect from all arms/teeth it would not be equal to the one which was originally present.

It is helpful economically too, because now lesser metal is required!

Comment: I understand that by laminating the conductor we reduced the eddy currents but what about the current that can pass within the conductor from a power source? Would there be change? Imagine we had a conductor that had current $I$ that passes through it and we moved it in a magnetic field $B$, would laminating the conductor reduce the current coming from the source?

Comment: First of all then we would not be talking about eddy currents, and secondly even that would be reduced because while laminating we have removed parts of the conductor, its area has been irreparibly cut down, due to net increases in resistance any constant potential source would give less current now.

Comment: There is a system, that requires a conductor to carry a certain amount of current, its it possible to reduce the eddy currents when passing a magnetic field(or in a changing magnetic field). Now, we could break the conductor's area and split the current up from 100A in a large piece into 10Amps on 10 pieces and that would be a reasonable solution? Maintaining the same total current, and reducing eddy current losses?

Comment: It would indeed be the same total current, but since I haven't seen/read about any such device I would not comment much on it until I get to know something about it.

Comment: I agree, its just a theory until practiced I guess. Yet from all the principles of EM, it should work. Reduced Eddy currents and same value of current but divided into multiple conductors.

Comment: Another question though, when we have multiple conductors with the same direction of I, we have  attractive forces acting on them correct? Like to wires in parallel that have the same direction of I they attract. What about this?

Comment: What about it? They would attract but magnetic forces are weak, the structural strength is enough to hold the device together. Btw, if u r satisfied why havent u accepted my answer?

Comment: Why would the magnetic forces be weak? Two parallel conductors carrying a lot of current could generate massive forces.  I am certainly satisfied with your answer, this is just another one.

Comment: The force is related to current as $\mu I_1 I_2$ and $\mu $ is of thr order of $10^{-7} $ I don't know what kind of current you are talking  about, but I see a very feeble force here!

Answer (score 1):

"Breaking" up the conductor has to do with breaking up possible paths of closed current loops that are induced by a time-varying magnetic field. The direction of the breaks matter as well. For instance, assuming the conducting of your top diagram has thickness coming out of the screen, then the planar breaks need to be coming into and out of the screen. If they run parallel to the screen, then they won't reduce the eddy current by much.

Comment: What about the current capacity?

Comment: What is the current capacity? Do you mean the total resistance  or the resistivity of the material? I don't believe "current capacity" has a well-defined meaning in physics.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is current affected in any way? Reduced maybe due to an increase of resistance

Comment: It has nothing to do with changing the resistance. Breaking up the conductor is purely a geometric effect. Look up "lamination", that's the more common name for it.

Comment: Thus, I wouldn't worry about current being reduced at all... I assumed this would change the conductor's electrical properties too, making it weaker and the amount of current it could carry would be less.

Comment: You will see reduced current but only because your losses will be reduced.

Comment: @Brad please explain.

Comment: @Key, if your losses go down (which they will if you reduce eddy currents in your steel), then the power drawn by the motor will go down (assuming the output power is the same).  Generally voltage input into a motor is kept the same, so that means reduced input power will lead to reduced current.

Comment: @Key: I think you're going down the wrong path by thinking about weakening the moving conductor. The gaps in the conductor can be close to infinitely small, and you can fill the breaks with glue or any other non-conducting substance that might be stronger than the conductor and the reduction of induced eddy currents will still occur.